# Custom Pouchdb build node.js vs browser?

Tags: node.js, pouchdb

I'm eager to use Pouchdb on both the server-side and browser however I'm a bit concerned to the size.  I'm using grunt and bower to build the project and noticed that the pouchdb.min.js generated from that, and from the npm package.json install are exactly the same.  No big deal, however the min size is 148k and includes support for everything, leveldb, localstorage, etc.

Should I passing some argument or setting some config variable to make custom builds (browser vs node)?

It's convinient to have a single/generic dist file, however at 148k, it's nearly double the size of even jquery.min

Thanks for any feedback,
Paul

I did notice some detection checks:

For example this line in index.js (referenced in the main of package.son):

```js
if (!process.browser) {
  var ldbAdapter = require('./adapters/leveldb/leveldb');
  PouchDB.adapter('leveldb', ldbAdapter, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, back in May when you asked this question, we had some bugs in the Browserify configuration causing LevelDB, Buffer, and other unnecessary Node modules to be browserified with the bundle. Today the size is a more reasonable ~47KB min+gzip.